# Disable JavaScript in iframe/div

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am making a small HTML page editor. The editor loads a file into an iframe. From there, it could add, modify, or delete the elements on the page with new attributes, styles, etc. The problem with this, is that JavaScript (and/or other programming languages) can completely modify the page when it loads, before you start editing the elements. So when you save, it won't save the original markup, but the modified page + your changes.

So, I need some way to disable the JavaScript on the iframe, or somehow remove all the JavaScript before the JavaScript starts modifying the page. (I figure I'll have to end up parsing the file for PHP, but that shouldn't be too hard) I considered writing a script to loop through all the elements, removing any  tags, onclick's, onfocus's, onmouseover's, etc. But that would be a real pain.

Does anyone know of an easier way to get rid of JavaScript from running inside an iframe?

UPDATE: unless I've missed something, I believe there is no way to simply 'disable JavaScript.' Please correct me if I'm wrong. But, I guess the only way to do it would be to parse out any script tags and JavaScript events (click, mouseover, etc) from a requested page string.

Comment: This talks about traversing the page with javascript and removing each occurance one by one: http://www.manticmoo.com/articles/jeff/programming/javascript/removing-javascript-with-javascript.php

Comment: That article talks about removing script nodes, which I don't believe will "un-execute the js" that was executed when the script was loaded. 
I really don't understand the question. What is the file loaded into the iframe? Are you allowing the user to type any html into the iframe? Where is all this javascript on your page coming from? It sounds like you have control over the contents of the file

Comment: The "manticmoo" URL doesn't seem to work, but it's still available via Wayback Machine (archive.org): http://web.archive.org/web/20070128100901/http://www.manticmoo.com/articles/jeff/programming/javascript/removing-javascript-with-javascript.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the same solution adopted by CKEditor, of which you have a demo [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo).
By switching from RTE mode to view source mode, you can enter some JavaScript and see the result, which is a replacement of the JS node in a safely encoded string.
If you are in **view source** mode, by entering some JS line like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// comment
alert('Ciao');
</script>
```

you will see it rendered this way when going back to **rich text editor** mode:

```
<!--{cke_protected}%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3E%0D%0A%2F%2F%20comment%0D%0Aalert('Ciao')%3B%0D%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E-->
```

I think it is one of the easiest and effective way, since the RegExp to parse JS nodes is not complex.
An example:

```
var pattern = /<script(\s+(\w+\s*=\s*("|').*?\3)\s*)*\s*(\/>|>.*?<\/script\s*>)/;
var match = HTMLString.match(pattern); // array containing the occurrences found
```

(Of course, to replace the script node you should use the replace() method).

Regards.

Comment: Answering to your update: yes, the server-side validation task is mandatory, but the issue you may want to solve in a client-side environment is the incorrect behaviour of iframes which users could inject some simple JavaScript to do something allowed. My practical experience of this issue was with a user who entered inside the editable iframe a simple script to import a form inside another iframe from another domain, which drove into a redirect of the editor page to a blank page. Though the imported iframe worked perfectly in the preview, the editor was unreachable after the code insertion.

Comment: @William you are right, that task should be performed by manipulating the attributes string, I provided a POC.

Comment: Be carefull this won't protect you against any XSS attack for the reasons pointed out here : https://medium.com/javascript-security/avoiding-xss-via-markdown-in-react-91665479900
With only this "protection" you would be vulnerable to javascript links, or scripts injected inside "onError" of images, for instance.

Answer (score 47):

HTML5 introduces [the `sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) on the iframe that, if empty, disables JavaScript loading and execution.

Comment: While this is the solution I was looking for, note that it does much more than just disable the javascript like the OP is asking for. [See here for details (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your update is correct. You **must** assume that any input you receive from the user may contain malicious elements. Thus, you **must** validate on the server before accepting their input.

Answer (score 1):

You can set **Content Security Policy** as **script-src 'self'** in header. CSP will block any scripts other than from our own website. This way we can prevent any scripts from iframe changing the elements in our page.

You can get more information from here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/