# Editable iframe without allowing JavaScript to run

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

I have an iframe:

```
<iframe id="msgContainer" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

and I'd like to insert HTML into it, but not let any JavaScript that may be contained in the HTML run (this includes both `<script>` tags and `on*` attributes. I know how to insert HTML (just use `document.getElementById('msgContainer').contentDocument.body.innerHTML=myHTML` but I'd like to prevent any JS in `myHTML` from running. The way I've tried to do this is by using the `sandbox` attribute and only allowing same-origin, but JS still runs. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable JavaScript in iframe/div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689455/disable-javascript-in-iframe-div)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that post. It doesn't exactly answer my question because: 1. I mentioned the sandbox attribute, but couldn't find a way to edit the `iframe` content while preventing JS execution with sandbox. 2. The first answer's only useful suggestion is regex which does not work as regex is not context free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any answer other than to parse out the JS from an html string inserted into the iframe. Here's my code (if it helps anyone else):

```
/** Removes javascript from html string
 * html: the string to be cleaned
*/
function clean(html) {
    function stripHTML(){
        html = html.slice(0, strip) + html.slice(j);
        j = strip;
        strip = false;
    }

    var strip = false,
    lastQuote = false,
    tag = false;
    const prefix = "ANYTHING",
    sandbox = " sandbox=''";

    for(var i=0; i<html.length; i++){
        if(html[i] === "<" && html[i+1] && isValidTagChar(html[i+1])) {
            i++;
            tag = false;
            /* Enter element */
            for(var j=i; j<html.length; j++){
                if(!lastQuote && html[j] === ">"){
                    if(strip) {
                        stripHTML();
                    }
                    /* sandbox iframes */
                    if(tag === "iframe"){
                        var index = html.slice(i, j).toLowerCase().indexOf("sandbox");
                        if(index > 0) {
                            html = html.slice(0, i+index) + prefix + html.slice(i+index);
                            j += prefix.length;
                        }
                        html = html.slice(0, j) + sandbox + html.slice(j);
                        j += sandbox.length;
                    }
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
                if(!tag && html[j] === " "){
                    tag = html.slice(i, j).toLowerCase();
                }
                if(lastQuote === html[j]){
                    lastQuote = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if(!lastQuote && html[j-1] === "=" && (html[j] === "'" || html[j] === '"')){
                    lastQuote = html[j];
                }
                /* Find on statements */
                if(!lastQuote && html[j-2] === " " && html[j-1] === "o" && html[j] === "n"){
                    strip = j-2;
                }
                if(strip && html[j] === " " && !lastQuote){
                    stripHTML();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    html = stripScripts(html);
    return html;
}

/** Returns whether or not the character is a valid first character in a tag
 * str: the first character
*/
function isValidTagChar(str) {
    return str.match(/[a-z?\\\/!]/i);
}

/** Strips scripts from a string of html
 * html: the string of html to be stripped
*/
// NOTE: <script> tags won't run in this context
function stripScripts(html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
      scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```