# Prevent page to jumping to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to integrate wetransfer into a website through an iframe, but I'm having a problem when the page loads, it jumps half-way down page, so it focuses on the iframe, instead of opening at the top of the page.

From what I can tell, there is a script on the wetransfer site that's telling it to jump to that section, instead starting at the top of the page. How can I get it to ignore the script by wetransfer or after the iframe's loaded to tell it to move back to the top of the page?

With jquery I tried $('html').scrollTop(0); after initiating the iframe, but it still doesn't work.

On the website I have jquery calculate the height of the user's screen and then set the header to that size, with a full background and navigation and than the iframe starts below that. So setting the position to absolute or anything along those lines, wouldn't work.

I created a very simple jsfiddle example just to show how the page opens scrolled halfway down the page. It only does this when the iframe source is wetransfer and not with any other source.

https://jsfiddle.net/dbruning22/c0s6mhkv/6/

HTML

```
<header>
  Some Header information and navigation
</header>
<div class="main">
  <iframe src="https://www.wetransfer.com/" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
header { 
  background: green;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an anchor at the top of your page like this:

HTML

```
<header>
<a id="focus" href="#focus"></a>
  Some Header information and navigation
</header>
```

On page load use this JS:

```
document.getElementById("focus").focus();
```

Comment: Tried it, but nothing happens. Still jumps to the middle of the page.

Comment: Can you share the link to your site?

Comment: Here's a link to the site: goo.gl/UVkWph

Comment: I tried it on IE edge, firefox 45 and chrome 49 with now issues. Try pressing CTRL+F5 to refresh the page.

Comment: hahaha... how annoying. I wasted how many hours yesterday trying to fix this. Checked in Firefox and IE and didn't cause the problem, but was still doing it in Chrome. Tried clearing my browser cache and stopped doing it. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1) You initially hide the iframe by setting the display to none:

```
<iframe id="bmap" src="xxx.xxxx.xxx" style="display:none;"  frameborder="0">
```

2) Once the page has loaded, then show the iframe using jquery or javascript:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    $("#bmap").show();
}
```

This worked for me across browsers

Comment: GOATED. thank you. We were using `opacity:0` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

As none of the above worked for me after numerous tests, another trick, because a lot of sites now have a "scroll to top" button, especially useful if page structure cannot be easily modified (like a wordpress theme ...):

```
  jQuery(".scroll-top-button").trigger("click");
```

Just forcing a click on that button ... that is really cross browser :-) (if jquery supported of course) ....

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a blunt solution, but you can block all scripts from running in the iframe using the [`sandbox` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868813).

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com" style="width: 100%; height: 250px" sandbox>
```

NB: An empty value blocks all same-origin resources, including images. You might prefer `sandbox="allow-same-origin"`.