# Page scrolls to iframe automatically once it's done loading, any way to stop this?

Tags: iframe, scroll, load, onload

You can see an example on the live website here: http://fryert.uk/dp.php

Essentially the page will jump to an iframe once it loads, and I'd rather it didn't do this, could anyone please help?

The site is using Bootstrap V4.1.3.

I originally thought it was only happening on Google Doc embeds, but this seems to be most/all iframes. I've removed the ones that I can, but have to keep these in place.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <iframe src="https://xd.adobe.com/embed/6f696869-d9ae-4617-5f01-8f5644bcf23d-1958/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result is that the page loads without scrolling, but it jumps to the last iframe to load.

Comment: Your question might have been answered here, you can try the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775563/11310795